# Masonry - Images overlap when using the HTML implementation method

Tags: jquery-masonry, overlapping

My Masonry "bricks" or items are overlapping when I load the page sometimes. But when I make my browser window smaller and then bigger, the items displays correctly. I'm using the HTML implementation method. The URL to my page is [www.humansofjohannesburg.org](http://www.humansofjohannesburg.org).

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

```
<div class="hoj js-masonry" id="container" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 247, "itemSelector": ".hoj-item", "gutter": 10, "isResizeBound": true }'>
    <!-- ITEM -->
    <div class="hoj-item">
        <div class="hoj-image">
            <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="hoj-intro">
            Content text goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ITEM -->
    <div class="hoj-item">
        <div class="hoj-image">
            <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="hoj-intro">
            Content text goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ITEM -->
    <div class="hoj-item">
        <div class="hoj-image">
            <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="hoj-intro">
            Content text goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ITEM -->
    <div class="hoj-item">
        <div class="hoj-image">
            <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="hoj-intro">
            Content text goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I reload page many times but it is working perfectly at my end. Please tell us exact scenario where bricks overlapping. Most probably your JS is not loading properly when you reload page.

Comment: Well it does load correctly sometimes. Like when I went to it now it loaded fine. But when I refreshed the page, 5 of the smaller images were on top of each other on the right hand side. After I refreshed about 5 times it loaded correctly again.

Comment: A colleague helped me. The Masonry JS loaded before the images loaded which then can't calculate the image height and width. I also replaced the HTML method with the jQuery method which is much better and also placed that in a js file in the <head>.

It now loads perfectly.